# Intercepting routes nextjs not rendering Modal

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, next.js13, app-router

When trying to use the intercepting routes feature of nextjs' new app router to use it with a Modal, the Modal never gets rendered and only the url changes.

---

My project structure looks like this:

- **/app**

  - **@modal**

    - **(.)user**

      - **[id]**

        - page.js
  - **user**

    - **[id]**

      - page.js
  - page.js

---

The root page.js contains a  component that links to /user/someUUID. When clicking on that link only the URL changes and the Modal never gets rendered.

I used this example code as a reference: https://github.com/vercel-labs/nextgram

Which works perfectly fine. I use the exact same Modal component from the example.

---

My /@modal/(.)user/[id]/page.js:

```
'use client'

import Modal from "../../../../components/modal"

export default function UserModal({ params: { id: userId } }) {
    alert("in modal page")

    return (
        <Modal>
            <p>{userId}</p>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

My /user/[id]/page.js:

```
'use client'

export default function UserPage({ params }) {

    return (
        <p>{params.id}</p>
    )
}
```

---

The alert in the Modal page never triggers but the page does get compiled. I got no warnings or errors or whatsoever. Does anyone know what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

if you look at the [vercel example here](https://github.com/vercel-labs/nextgram/blob/main/app/layout.js), that model is passed to the layout file as `prop`

```
export default function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <GithubCorner />
        {props.children}
        {props.modal}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this step, hopefully will solve your problem. because I faced this issue too.

1. You should create **layout.js** in the app folder and then call modal props after/before children props because you using *@modal* as a slot.
2. And then create **default.js** file inside *@modal* folder and make it return null to ensure that the contents of the modal don't get rendered when it's not active.

**layout.js**

```
export default async function Layout(props: {
  // ...
  auth: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      {props.auth}
    </>
  )
}
```

**default.js**

```
export default function Default() {
  return null
}
```

Your project structure should be look like this after following the step:

- /app

  - @modal

    - (.)user

      - [id]

        - page.js
    - default.js
  - user

    - [id]

      - page.js
  - page.js
  - layout.js

Comment: if I navigate to the link it is being intercepted however the parent firing server actions again? what am i doing differently? It only happens if you navigate to the link first time after the first click I guess nextjs caches it.